# Prototype and display:none

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, prototypejs

I have this slideshow:

```
<div class="row-3">
                    <div class="slider-wrapper">
                        <div class="slider">
                          <ul class="items">
                            <li><img src="images/slider-img4.jpg" alt="">
                                <strong class="banner">
                                    <strong class="b1"></strong>
                                    <strong class="b2">Operaciones realistas</strong>
                                    <strong class="b3"></strong>
                                </strong>
                            </li>
                            <li><img src="images/slider-img1.jpg" alt="">
                                <strong class="banner">
                                    <strong class="b1">Pasión por Volar</strong>
                                    <strong class="b2">Realismo</strong>
                                    <strong class="b3"></strong>
                                </strong>
                            </li>
                            <li><img src="images/slider-img2.jpg" alt="">
                                <strong class="banner">
                                    <strong class="b1">Pasión por Volar</strong>
                                    <strong class="b2">Realismo</strong>
                                    <strong class="b3"></strong>
                                </strong>
                            </li>
                            <li><img src="images/slider-img3.jpg" alt="">
                                <strong class="banner">
                                    <strong class="b1"></strong>
                                    <strong class="b2">Simulación</strong>
                                    <strong class="b3"></strong>
                                </strong>
                            </li>                           
                          </ul>
                          <a class="prev" href="#">prev</a>
                          <a class="next" href="#">prev</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Here is the class items:

```
.items {display:none}
```

At the same time I´m running prototype.js. But If I run it I can see the slideshow. It´s because i´m using display:none in .item. But if I remove display:none the slideshow doesn´t work so I need it. And If I removed prototype.js the slideshow works but the scrip that is using prototype doesn´t work.

Comment: display: none hides the things so how can it work fine?

Answer (score 0):

PrototypeJS needs the display:none to be in a `style` attribute and not in the CSS. Remove the .items{display:none} style and use UL start tag like this:

```
<ul class="items" style="display:none">
```

This will make .show() work properly, which I think is your core issue.